# Is "bench press" a valid name for the bench used for bench pressing?

Tags: terminology

Someone asked this on Russian.SE:

> How should one express the concept of "take turns" in Russian?
>
> For example, taking turns using the bench press in the gym, or taking turns on the Xbox controller or iPad.

I was under impression that "bench press" was the exercise, not the apparatus, but they have reassured me you can call that the apparatus too:

> If the bench comes with a barbell and safety rack and is clearly designed for bench pressing, then the whole apparatus can be referred to as a bench press. So, "Someone's already using the squat rack" and "Someone's already using the pull-up bar", but "Someone's already using the bench press". This might be colloquial, though.

So can you call a bench used for bench pressing a "bench press"?

Comment: The *bench press* referred to here is the "equipment"/"device"/"unit" used to carry out the exercise known as "the bench press" -- it is not the physical bench. The question is a NARQ.

Comment: @Kris: so can you call this equipment "bench press"?

Comment: Also known as "workout bench".

Comment: @Kris: so can you call a workout bench a "bench press"? Does the phrase "I bought a used bench press for $99" make sense?

Comment: @Kris This is a somewhat different usage from *drill press* or *steam press* or *printing press*. I don't see why it isn't a valid question.

Comment: At the gym I go to, you'd be well understood if you called it a "weight bench"

Comment: You example in the comments of "bought a used..." would say that you bought a resistance machine rate than a free weights bench.

Comment: bench press is the thing and the activity. Sorry, did anyone say that??

Comment: @Lambie: yes, Kris did, in their very first comment, which is something not obvious to me. Let me repeat myself: does the phrase "I bought a used bench press for $99" make sense?

Comment: @Quassnoi 1  YES< it means you bought the physical object on which bench presses are done by a person.

Comment: @Quassnoi "bench press" means 1) the exercise of pushing up a barbell lying on your back on a bench 2) the whole apparatus: a padded bench plus the rack to hold the barbell above your head. If it doesn't include the rack, it's just a bench.

Comment: @Mitch: the source of my confusion is that a "bench press" (the apparatus), if we call it that, is not a kind of press. I understand it might be a metonymy (like we could call a steam engine just a "steam" in some contexts), but was wondering if this metonymy has already rooted in the language, or it's still perceived as such ("- Is it a steam or a diesel engine? - It's a steam"). Could you please post it as an answer? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is metonymy. The apparatus has been given the same name as the exercise of pressing up with the chest/arms. "I bought a used bench press for $99" makes entire sense and is not remarkable in any way.

Comment: @Mitch: could you please post this as an answer? I'm going to mark this as accepted.

Comment: Laurel's answer is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term "bench press" *is* used to refer to the equipment:

[image: Weider Pro 345 B Mid Width bench press]

You can call it this, but the usage is rare. It is *usually* called a "weight bench". Or just a bench.

You can verify this by browsing online stores that sell this type of equipment. It's a fairly consistent pattern across different retailers, actually.

Answer (score 1):

"Bench press" as an item (not the exercise) is usually used to refer to a machine for bench pressing. It would include a stack of weights, a bench and a mechanism to transfer your force to the weights. They're less common than they used to be, as chest press machines take up less space.

If you bench press with a barbell or dumbbells, what you use is just a *bench*. If you're not already talking about a gym context, *weight bench* or *gym bench* might be a good way to be clear.

Your case of a bench with a rack attached is interesting. *I* also use this for other exercises when the other benches are busy, and have never heard anyone refer to it as a bench *press* in my gym

But if you used *bench press*, people would almost understand - they'd just think you used a machine rather than free weights for the same exercise.

Comment: Please see my comment at OP.

Answer (score 0):

If the sole purpose of the bench is to do bench presses, and there are other benches in the room, then it seems like the logical alternative would be to refer to it as "the bench press bench".  This seems silly, and unecessarily pedantic.

If it was the only bench, then you could just call it "the bench" if you want, although some people might not realise what you're referring to.

So, yes, let people call the bench "the bench press", if it leads to clearer communication, since the purpose of language is to allow clear communication, rather than "satisfy the rules of grammar", which in fact constantly evolve to suit the needs of the population.

Answer (score 0):

Just call it the **press bench** instead of "bench press," that's how I do it.

I don't know if it's a valid proof: but if you put it in google, the suggestions come up:

> *Press bench* -- dimentions/for sale/workout/equipment

vs.

> *Bench press* -- form/record/chart/set

Comment: Ah, but the *press bench* is where reporters sit at a baseball game.

Comment: @HotLicks Oh, that's why everyone in the gym hurriedly tries to spiff themselves up, every time I announce "I'm goin for the press bench." ;)